# События Phalcon

Tags: php, события, phalcon

К примеру есть два контроллера - `UserController` и `CommentsController`

Псевдокод

```
class UserController
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    var_dump($comments); //если модуль комментариев активен, отдаем комметарии, иначе ничего не отдаем 
  }
}

class CommentsController
{
  $comments = [];

  public function afterUserIndexAction()
  {
   return $comments
  }
}
```

Как подтянуть `$comments` при вызове метода `indexAction` контроллера `UserController` ? Я так понимаю что нужно копать в сторону событий, но реализовать на `Phalcon` как не пробовал не получается. Т.е. в итоге хочу получить что-то вроде системы плагинов, чтобы можно было расширять один модуль с помощью другого, как-то так.

Документацию по событиям перечитывал раз 10 :(

Answer (score 1):

Реализация в корне неверная. Ты не понял самой сути плагинов и контролеров. Контроллер реагирует на пользовательские действия, а ты пытаешься заявить, что контроллер - это плагин.

Что плохо???

1. Во-первых все контроллеры должны наследоваться от базового контроллера Phalcon, тогда в них будет доступно DI и EventManager
2. Во-вторых, ты пытаешься получить комментарии в indexAction, но "событие" у тебя называется "**after**UserIndexAction".
3. Где кидание события? Кто кинул событие, кто его обработал? Непонятно.

Как нужно сделать:

```
    use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller as PhController;

    class UserController extends PhController
    {
        public function indexAction()
        {
            $this->getEventsManager()->fire('user:comments');
            $comments = $this->dispatcher->getParam('comments');
            if ($comments) {
                var_dump($comments); //если модуль комментариев активен, отдаем комметарии, иначе ничего не отдаем
            }
        }
    }

    use Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin;
    use Phalcon\Events\Event;

    class CommentsPlugin extends Plugin
    {

        protected $comments = [];

        public function comments(Event $event)
        {
            $this->dispatcher->setParam('comments', $this->comments);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Ну и потом в инициализации DI:

```
$di['eventsManager'] = function () {
    $manager = new \Phalcon\Events\Manager();
    $manager->attach('user', new CommentsPlugin);
    return $manager;
};
```